# Getting the error: expected identifier or '(' before '{' token

Tags: c

Need help with the error: expected identifier or '(' before '{' token.  I have a main file and a sort heap file.  This three files are all separate and I am trying to run this files on a terminal.  The command line I use to run this files on terminal is:

```
gcc -std=c99 -DRAND -DHEAP -DTYPE=double -DPRINT main.c srtheap.c
```

This is my code:

```
/*
 *
 *  srt.h file
 *
 */

#ifndef SRT_H  
#define SRT_H  
#include < string.h >  
#define MAX_BUF 256

#define swap(qx,qy,sz) 

{                                             
  do                                                                 
   char buf[MAX_BUF];                                              
   char *q1 = qx;                                                  
   char *q2 = qy;                                                  
   for (size_t m, ms = sz; ms > 0; ms -= m, q1 += m, q2 += m) {    
       m = ms < sizeof(buf) ? ms : sizeof(buf);                    
       memcpy(buf, q1, m);                                         
       memcpy(q1, q2, m);                                          
       memcpy(q2, buf, m);                                         

  while (0)
}

void srtbubb(void *, size_t, size_t, int (*)(const void *, const void *));  
void srtheap(void *, size_t, size_t, int (*)(const void *, const void *));  
void srtinsr(void *, size_t, size_t, int (*)(const void *, const void *));  
void srtmerg(void *, size_t, size_t, int (*)(const void *, const void *));  

#endif /* SRT_H */
```

Comment: I can upload quickly the rest of the two files that associated if they are need someone to help me. But problem that run into is in this code block.

Comment: Isn't it `do {..} while(..)`?

Comment: The error that I am getting is regarding parenthesis before do.

Comment: Need to add `{` after `do` and 2 `}`s before `while`. Oh and I'm not sure if your macro will be replaced with this body.

Comment: I am new to C programming. Never done any work in C.

Comment: @user2479019: Agreed, then why not start with a good book which explains about valid syntax first?

Comment: Okay I did do adding of { after do and 2 }s before while. And ';' after while statement.  Getting error -  srt.h:17:error: expected identifier or '(' before 'do'

Comment: The do-while is not needed, you can just have a block between `{` and `}`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `#define` of a multi-line macro requires that you end each (except the last) line with `\`.  So you'd get:

```
#define swap(qx,qy,sz)                                              \
do {                                                                \
    char buf[MAX_BUF];                                              \
    char *q1 = qx;                                                  \
    char *q2 = qy;                                                  \
    for (size_t m, ms = sz; ms > 0; ms -= m, q1 += m, q2 += m) {    \
        m = ms < sizeof(buf) ? ms : sizeof(buf);                    \
        memcpy(buf, q1, m);                                         \
        memcpy(q1, q2, m);                                          \
        memcpy(q2, buf, m);                                         \
    }                                                               \
} while (0)
```

Be very careful to not have any white-space after the `\` because this will cancel the `\` and break the multi-line `#define`, which will result in hard to find compiler errors.

Comment: And in general if wrapping with a `do { ... } while` omit the semicolon on the last line when defining the macro.

Comment: @meaning-matters You need to leave in the `do{...}while(0)` : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154136/do-while-and-if-else-statements-in-c-c-macros

Comment: + you are not allowed at add any space after `\\`, btw nice name and nice location :)

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Thanks! Yes, that's what I wrote: 'no white-space after `\` :-)

Comment: @meaning-matters sorry didn't notice, btw you need to write two times \\ in comment if you are using `\``

Answer (score 6):

Your do-while loop has bad syntax regarding the braces (need a pair for the do-while, and a pair for the for-loop.  Also, you are missing semicolon after the `while`.  And you need the `\` for multiline macros.  Try this:

```
#define swap(qx,qy,sz)                                              \
do                                                                  \
{                                                                   \ 
   char buf[MAX_BUF];                                               \
   char *q1 = qx;                                                   \ 
   char *q2 = qy;                                                   \ 
   for (size_t m, ms = sz; ms > 0; ms -= m, q1 += m, q2 += m) {     \
       m = ms < sizeof(buf) ? ms : sizeof(buf);                     \
       memcpy(buf, q1, m);                                          \
       memcpy(q1, q2, m);                                           \
       memcpy(q2, buf, m);                                          \
   }                                                                \
} while (0)
```

Comment: srt.h:17: error: expected identifier or '(' before 'do'
    srt.h:28: error: expected identifier or '(' before 'while'
    In file included from srtheap.c:6:
    srt.h:17: error: expected identifier or '(' before 'do'
    srt.h:28: error: expected identifier or '(' before 'while'
    afsconnect1-27 ma524>:

Comment: In a macro definition like that, you *don't* want a semicolon after the `while (0)`. The semicolon will be added when the macro is invoked: `swap(x, y, z);`

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to `#define` a multi-line macro, which may or may not be what you intended.  In any case, you need to add the continuation character `\` to the end of each line (and fix your brackets):

```
#define swap(qx,qy,sz)   \
  do {                   \
   char buf[MAX_BUF];    \
   char *q1 = qx;        \
   char *q2 = qy;        \
   for (size_t m, ms = sz; ms > 0; ms -= m, q1 += m, q2 += m) {    \
       m = ms < sizeof(buf) ? ms : sizeof(buf);                    \
       memcpy(buf, q1, m);                                         \
       memcpy(q1, q2, m);                                          \
       memcpy(q2, buf, m);                                         \
       }                                                           \
   }                     \
while (0)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several mistakes/typos in `#define`ing `swap()`:

This should do it (at least compile):

```
#define swap(qx,qy,sz) \
  do { \ 
    char buf[MAX_BUF]; \
    char *q1 = (qx); \
    char *q2 = (qy); \
    for (size_t m, ms = (sz); ms > 0; ms -= m, q1 += m, q2 += m) \
    { \
      m = ms < sizeof(buf) ? ms : sizeof(buf); \
      memcpy(buf, q1, m); \
      memcpy(q1, q2, m); \
      memcpy(q2, buf, m); \
    } \
  } while (0)
```

Note that defines may not have line break, so `\`is used to tell the preprocessor to joinf the lines.

Also it is advisable to put macro' s arguments in `()` when it is used, to avoid unwanted side effect after macro expansion.